# Cross-Validation for tuning parameter selection, Support Vector Machine in R

Tags: cross-validation

I am using 10-folds cross-validation to choosing the value of cost in Support Vector Machine by using R. I repeat cross validation 10 times and plot the test error. But the plot is strange! I hope I can have similar pattern each time but I fail. Could you tell me how to choose cost in this situation? [image: x-axis is cost, y-axis is the test error]

```
library(e1071)
my.cv.svm=function(x,y,Kfold,cost){
  n = nrow(x) 
  folds = sample(1:Kfold, n, replace=TRUE) 
  fold.error = rep(0, Kfold) 
  for (j in 1:Kfold){
     train<-x[folds!=j,]
     test<-x[folds==j,]
     svm.fit=svm(yfactor[folds!=j]~.,data=train,kernel="radial",cost=cost)
     svm.predict=predict(svm.fit,test)
     fold.error[j]=mean(svm.predict!=y[folds==j])
  }
  cv.error=sum(fold.error)/Kfold
  return(cv.error)
}
cost=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
test.error=rep(0,length(cost))
error10fold=rep(0,length(cost))
for (i in 1:length(cost)){
    error10fold[i]=my.cv.svm(x,yfactor,10,cost[i])
}
plot(cost,error10fold,type="b")
test.error=error10fold
##repeat it 9 times
times=2:10
for (d in times){
error10fold=rep(0,length(cost))
for (i in 1:length(cost)){
    error10fold[i]=my.cv.svm(x,yfactor,10,cost[i])
}
test.error=test.error+error10fold
lines(cost,error10fold,type="b",col=d)
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please share your code. It is otherwise very hard for anyone to even guess what is going on here. – *Reviewer*

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I edit my question, I do not post the data set.